# Examining correctness of Neural Network using gradient check in Pybrain

Tags: neural-network, pybrain, gradient-descent

I wrote this dummy code to check the correctness of a simple network(according to the documentation [here](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/extending-structure.html)), but whenever I increase the number of inputs beyond 30, I get the following error:

("Incorrect Gradient", array[...])

('Incorrect module:', Full Connection 'Full Connection - 7': 'bias' ->hidden0', [...])

These square brackets in both the cases contain a huge array which I can't post here, owing to the size. In my actual code, I am trying to solve a classification problem with 62 inputs, so I need to build a network which can handle that many inputs. I also tried increasing the number of hidden layers, and the number of neurons in the hidden layer(I tried till even 50), but that didn't help. Here is the code:

```
import pybrain
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork  
from pybrain.tests.helpers import gradientCheck

n = buildNetwork(40,10, 1)
n.randomize()
gradientCheck(n)
```

I don't know if it is relevant here, nevertheless, I have 900 samples of data right now, and I am expecting another 1000 samples or so soon.

Comment: Just as an investigative test, what happens if you have the same size network but a much smaller dataset?  Do you get the same error?  Or is it only the combination of >30 inputs and 900 data cases?

Comment: The error that I have posted here is for the dummy code, which doesn't need a dataset. I guess the n.randomize() command must be randomly initializing the network.

Comment: On my computer I get the error as soon as the number of inputs gets to 19.  Given that there are different thresholds for the problem on your computer and mine, I'm thinking it's not intrinsic to the code, but maybe is a problem related to how much memory is used?  Just a guess.  Try it on a different computer and see if you get a different result, to test this theory.